# Visual Studio 2010 (Argument Exception)

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2010, arguments

I get the following exception: 'Cannot find the method on the object instance' when I hover over a property of one of my classes in Visual Studio 2010.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the target platform for the project from x86 to AnyCPU and rebuilt. Some of the projects in the solution were set to target AnyCPU and some x86, initially. Hope this helps someone ...